# E: Package 'synaptic' has no installation candidate error in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, apt, kali-linux, package-management, synaptic

So I'm currently trying to install the `'synaptic'` package manager in Kali Linux through `apt-get install`. But I'm getting an error that says `E: Package 'synaptic' has no installation candidate.`

I've tried the following:-

- `apt-get update`
- `apt-get upgrade`
- changed the mirror urls in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

But it's still not working, it would be great if someone can help me install this package:)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`synaptic` [was removed from Kali](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/synaptic) on June 27, so it was no longer installable from the Kali repositories.

A number of issues were fixed [in the package in Debian](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/synaptic), and it was re-imported in Kali on July 7.